# Conditional Formatting for Calender

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

Good day,
so I am trying to build a planning tool, where I am using a table with source data on one sheet, which I want to use to fill in cells with different colours in a calender sheet, depending on the job type for different dates.
I can get conditional formatting to display single tasks, but have problems applying the conditional formatting throughout, i.e. if I have two entries for the same person in the table, I want both of them displayed in the calender.
Anyone who can help?
[image: Table with source data][image: Calender, where i Want the different blocks be displayed][image: Conditional Formatting with Formulas, which I want to use to display periods from table in calnder]

Please see below example what I want the calender to show and what I want it to be based upon.
[image: This what I want the calnder to show][image: These are the values I want the calender to be based upon]

Comment: *I have two entries for the same person in the table, I want both of them displayed in the calender* If both entries share same cell, then only 1 CF rule can be seen.

Comment: What I am trying to do is, using the list above where you can enter start dates and duration, and then have them displayed as blocks for the calender for each person. I can only show one block, and it doesn't even match the person named in the list. I can't the formulas to work, as they seem to skip rows. Do you know, if the MATCH function might help here?

Comment: Could you add a manual expected output?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Please specify "manual expected output" :)

Comment: Could you post an example of how it should be? What is the result you want to get?

Comment: Please see below answer with pictures of what I want the calender to show :)

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/827882/how-to-highlight-calendar-cells-based-on-given-start-and-end-date